# How to access VueJS on codeanywhere

Tags: vue.js, codeanywhere

there.
I´m starting on VueJS, creating a project in codeanywhere:

```
npm install -g vue-cli
vue init webpack myProject
```

So, when i run `npm run dev`i get a

> Your application is running here: http://localhost:8080

Because, i am developing on a cloud based IDE, i´cant access http://localhost...
So, i access the way Codeanywhere publish when you create a project:

> https://myProject-XXXXXXXX.codeanyapp.com/

But i get a

> This Container is currently unaccessible.

Really appreciated any help.

Answer (score 4):

I created a vue.config.js file at the root (next to package.json) with content:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    allowedHosts: [
      '.codeanyapp.com'
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Codeanywhere documentation](https://docs.codeanywhere.com/connections/containerconfig.html#running-on-localhost):

You have to change the default IP so your Container could run externally.
Please change IP address on your container from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Work for me with nuxt.config.js :

```
server: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    timing: false
  },
```